# Error Invalid shorthand property initializer in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2020

```js
let will_pokemon = {
    pikachu: {
        species: 'Mouse pokemon',
        height: 0.4,
        weight: 5
    }
}

let samson_pokemon = {
    raichu = {
        species: 'Rare pokemon',
        height: 0.8,
        weight: 12
    }
}

let weight4 = samson_pokemon?.pikachu?.weight //check either object property available if not will be undefined

console.log(weight4)
```

Why I got error Invalid shorthand property initializer when running on my Chrome browser?

Comment: Fix: ``raichu: {``

Comment: Works fine for me on Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not use '=' inside [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). It should be `raichu : {`

```
let samson_pokemon = {
    raichu : {
        species: 'Rare pokemon',
        height: 0.8,
        weight: 12
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this.

```
let weight4 = (typeof samson_pokemon !== 'undefined') ? samson_pokemon.pikachu : samson_pokemon.weight;
```